# Find between lines start and end: awk with bash variables and add new paragraph everytime

Tags: awk

input:

```
xxx word1 xxx xxx
xxx xxxx word2
45
776
8
start
1
2
3
finish
45
3
6
```

awk code:

```
awk -v s="startpoint" -v e="finishpoint" '$0~s,$0~e' input >> output.
```

that code works perfectly by itself. But when I combine with others, it did not work. I like to start new paragraph so I put `printf "/n"` but it did not work either

```
awk -v s="start" -v e="finish" 'BEGIN { ORS="" } /#word1/ {gsub(/,/,"",$2); print $2 "\t"} /#word2/ {print $2, "\n"} $0~s,$0~e' input >> output
```

output:

```
start 1 2 3 finish
```

desirable output:

```
start

1

2

3

finish
```

Comment: When I run the code `awk -v s="start" -v e="finish" '$0~s,$0~e'` I get output with each line element remaining on a separate line, not all on one line as you have indicated. Is your real intention to have "dbl-spaced" output as in your "desireable output" above, or are you having trouble using the S.O. edit/display functions? Good luck.

Comment: Why do you set `ORS=""` if that's not what you want?

Comment: There are certain lines I like to extract  from a text file thats why I use. But only problem I couldnt figure out is that how can start new line everytime $0~s,$0~e. I tried $0~s,$0~e, {printf "/n"} but it did not work

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply add another variable to use as a flag variable to control printing. (e.g. `prn=0`, then when `start` is found set `prn=1` and print all lines if `prn=1`, then exit when `finish` is reached). For example you could do the following:

```
awk -v s="start" -v e="finish" -v prn=0 '
    BEGIN { ORS="" }
    $0~s { prn=1 }
    prn==1 { printf "%s\n\n", $0 }
    $0~e {exit}
' input
```

(**note:** it would be simpler to just leave the `ORS` as a newline)

**Example Use/Output**

Just pasting at the command line you would get:

```
$ awk -v s="start" -v e="finish" -v prn=0 '
>     BEGIN { ORS="" }
>     $0~s { prn=1 }
>     prn==1 { printf "%s\n\n", $0 }
>     $0~e {exit}
> ' input
start

1

2

3

finish
```

Which matches your output. (if you really don't want the blank lines, just remove one of the `'\n'` in the `printf` statement)

**To Find All `start` And `finish` Just Reset `prn` Flag Zero**

To not `exit` after the first `finish` but find all `start` to `finish` cases, you reset `prn=0`, e.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS=""; s="start"; e="finish"; prn=0 }
    $0~s { prn=1 }
    prn==1 { printf "%s\n\n", $0 }
    $0~e { prn=0 }
' input
```

(**note:** above I combined setting all variables in the `BEGIN` rule since you are using it anyway)

Now all `start` to `finish` sections will be output in the same way.

Let me know if you are asking for something slightly different or if you have further questions.

Comment: the code you wrote just found the first one, then stop there. There are a couple of start and finish in text file.  Thats why I just deleted {exit} at the end of your code still I can no differences. I want the code find all of them.

Comment: No problem, you just set `prn=0` instead of `exit`. I thought you were done after the `finish`. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and like to share with you guys.

```
awk -v s="start" -v e="finish" '$0~s,$0~e {print $0 "\t"}'
```

If you like to select which column you like to extract from text file, you may use

```
awk -v s="start" -v e="finish" '$0~s,$0~e {print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $4 "\t"}'
```